# Kivy + pyzbar does not decode QR properly on Android

Tags: python, android, kivy

I am working on a Kivy App that takes an image through:

```
texture = self.camera.texture
size = texture.size
pixels = texture.pixels
```

The information above is used for the following function:

```
import numpy
from PIL import Image

from pyzbar.pyzbar import decode

def convert_qr(size, pixels):
    
    pil_image = Image.frombytes(mode='RGBA', size=size,data=pixels)

    #This returns an array of length 480
    numpypicture = numpy.array(pil_image)

    # PC returns a list of 1
    # Android returns an empty list
    barcodes = decode(numpypicture)

    #barcode_info = barcodes[0].data.decode('utf-8') 

    return str(len(barcodes))
```

**Problem**

I know the problem comes from this line:

```
barcodes = decode(numpypicture)
```

but i don't know how to fix it. When I use the computer camera and run it the function returns '1' for str(len(barcodes)). When I use the android camera,  the function returns '0'. This means, the barcodes = decode(numpypicture) does not decode the 'numpypicture' properly.

I know for a fact that 'numpypicture' variables works because both PC and Android camera return 480 when i return len(numpypicture). It is only after the barcodes = decode(numpypicture) line that the result between PC and Android Camera is different. (They are scanning the same QR Image)

Any idea how i might debug this?

Comment: I tried this same code with Barcodes and it works. It does not work with QR code for some reason. i modified the code to barcodes = decode(numpypicture, symbols = [ZBarSymbol.QRCODE] to specify the QR code scan but it still does not work. Any idea?

Comment: I solved this issue in another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70895762/pyzbar-on-android-doesnt-read-qrcodes-but-reads-barcodes/70954786#70954786). I hope it fixes your problem

Answer (score 0):

It might be a dependency issue. Make sure that you add `libzbar` to your requirements field in `buildozer.spec` file. pyzbar depends on this to work. Here is some more info about this from a repo I found [zbarcamera](https://github.com/kivy-garden/zbarcam)

Comment: I added libzbar in the requirements. The problem is still there.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow the picture is mirrored in Android so flipping it with e.g. opencv if the platform is Android solves this problem:

```
if platform is 'android':
    numpypicture = cv2.flip(numpypicture, 0)
barcodes = decode(numpypicture)
```